# PIPELINE: logging URLS that fail to support pipelining heuristics

Tags: xcode, cocoa-touch, pipeline

I am trying to integrate twitter into an iOS app using Ben Gottlieb's [Twitter-OAuth-iPhone](https://github.com/bengottlieb/Twitter-OAuth-iPhone) library.  When I run this on the simulator it works fine.  However, when I run it on an iPhone it does not work.  I get the following messages in debugger:

```
> PIPELINE: logging URLS that fail to support pipelining heuristics
> PIPELINE: Heuristics failed for: twitter.com
```

Any ideas what is going on here, and how I can get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I know what this is, but I've only seen this in iOS 5. Due to the NDA I can't give details though on here. Post it in the Apple Developer Forum and i'll answer your post once you post the link.